# Generate new key inside EVALSHA

Tags: lua, redis

[Documentation](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL) states that keys must be passed explicitly, so if using Redis cluster, the command can be forwarded to the appropriate node.

However, does this apply to new keys as well? For example, if I have a script to register a new entity, and such script is creating dynamically a totally new key composed by the result of INCR and a literal, would it be a problem for Redis cluster?

The alternative would be to call to INCR in a separate operation and pass the key to the script as KEY[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're careful to ensure that your new key is hashed to the same server as your other keys, I think you'll be fine.

That is, the important thing with Cluster is not just to declare your keys up front, but to make sure that all the keys your script operates on are located on the same server. You can do that with your keys by using [hash tags](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags). If you construct your new key in such a way that it hashes to the same slot as your others, I think it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! So if I pass to the script the key that holds the ids like `{product:}ids` and then generate a key inside the script named `{product:}1`, it will be safe?

Comment: @vtortola: Yes, I believe so.